# "Cabbage and beets together sounds good." or "Cabbage and beets together sound good."

Tags: grammatical-number

Cabbage and beets is not a single dish.  Does the word 'together' make the subject singular?

Comment: I would say "Cabbage and beets together sounds ..." (but would not complete the sentence with "good").  But I suspect that a number of people would go the other way (I mean, say "sound", not say "good").

Comment: The fact that they are not a single dish doesn’t mean they can’t be a single _notional unit_. Cabbage and beets _sound_ horrible together, but cabbage and beets together with each other _sounds_ disgusting. Either way, as @HotLicks said, ‘good’ is one thing it/they definitely do(es) not sound.

Comment: "sounds". Even without the "together", if it's plausible that you're talking about a single meal, "sounds" sounds better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, the verb "to sound" is a little tricky, because, depending on interpretation, almost any "plural" subject could actually be singular.

For example, we could interpret your phrase as:

> "Cabbage and beets together" sounds good.

Where "cabbage and beets together" is viewed as a singular phrase.  You can even extend this to:

> "Cabbages" sounds good.

---

More directly to the point, is the subject here singular or plural? In this case, either work.

It all has to do with your use of "cabbage".  Cabbage is both a singular and a mass noun (countable and uncountable).  In this way, "cabbage and beets" is the same thing as "macaroni and cheese".

We have a tendency to describe dishes in English uses uncountable nouns: ice cream and chocolate syrup, pumpkin with butter squash, spaghetti and meatballs, etc.  These dishes are all single dishes, so we treat them as single items.

In your case, "cabbage and beets" sounds like a single dish, which is why I would treat them as a singular item.  However, you are also listing two subjects, so I would also accept it as plural.  The earlier context of the conversation may also help here.

One way to overcome the issues to to explicitly pluralize "cabbages".  Then, you would say "Cabbages and beets are...".  Again, they could be a singular dish, and then referring to it singularly would be acceptable, but "cabbages and beets" is broadly inconsistent with dish names.

Comment: Thanks, Nick2253 and others.  As for context, this was a question my wife asked:  "Do you want to eat cabbage and beets for dinner?"  But it was a combination of foods we haven't had before, hence my note that the combination is not contextually a single dish.  But then I wondered if 'together' unifies plural into a singular?  Great insights on the uncountable nouns aspect and use of 'to sound.'

Answer (score -3):

This question is in the domain of sequential vs parallel logic.

- {{A **and** B} {plural verbal phrase}}
- {{A **or** B} {singular verbal phrase}}

For examples,

- Muniandee **and** Kolarry are getting married.
- Either Muniandee **or** Shanmugha is getting married.
- Idrus **and** Mokhtar have a car each.
- I am not sure if Idrus **or** Mokhtar has a car.
- Kamisah **and** Satya are from Yogjakarta.
- I need to know if Kamisah **or** Satya is from Yogjakarta.

Items conjoined by *AND* sit inside the same set, and therefore present a plural set.

Items conjoined by *OR* each sits in mutually exclusive singular sets, and only one yet-to-be-determined set is chosen to be presented.

Plural members in singular set:

- Andy **and** Anne are housemates.

Singular members in multiple-but-chose-one sets:

- Do you know if Andy, Joe **or** Mary likes root beer?

Plural members in multiple sets

- Zedekiah **and** Zerubabel, **and**, Joseph **and** Potiphar, are going to work as partners.

Multiple-but-choose-one sets with plural membership

- Do you know if Zedekiah *and* Zerubabel, **or**, Joseph **and** Potiphar, are going to work as partners?

Tainted by possibility of a plural set

- David **and** Jonathan, **or** Saul himself, have to fight the Philistines.

Contextual plural set

- Cabbage **and** beets are vegetables.

Contextual singular set

- {{Composite-noun} singular-verbal phrase}
- "*Cabbage and beets together*" is a nice phrase.
- *Cabbage and beets together* sounds like a good combination.

Comment: Then why does everyone above agree that "Cabbage and beets together sounds..." is the correct form?

Comment: Downvoter: "Johan and Mariam are going to school" or "Johan and Mariam is going to school" ??? You cannot depend on "feelings". And "idiomatic" is a stale overused excuse to violate normal rules of English.

Comment: I detect that you're Pist.

Comment: Whatever -- I added two more cases, which would be completely explain the difference.

Comment: Nice try, no dice.

Comment: Then explain why "Johan and Mariam is going to school" is not acceptable.

Comment: "Johan and Mariam" is not a single conceptual entity.

Comment: Exactly ! ! ! ! !

Comment: When all fails, fall back to the simplicity of mathematics.

Comment: I see, Blessed Geek.  Thank you.  The key is that "together" makes this case a contextual singular set.

Comment: I think the confusion on downvotes may be because the first lines of your answer makes it sound like if you use 'A and B', then the verbal phrase must be plural.  But your last point on Contextual singular set seems to contradict that pattern.

Answer (score -4):

When saying this sentence aloud, I take the "cabbage and beets" and replace them with "they" because there are two items joined with "and". Restating the sentence using "they": They sound like a good dish. So, "Cabbage and beets sound like a good dish" would be my conclusion.